# What does “to give a buck about” mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

What does the expression *to give a buck about* mean?

I could not find the definition of that expression in my dictionaries. I think it shows a lack of interest about something. Am I wrong?

Comment: Very possibly a combination of "don't give a f**k about" and "wouldn't give two cents for" (with inflation).

Answer (score 1):

*To give a **b**uck about* is either a typo or a minced oath for *to give a **f**uck about*.

Comment: Now that is a wild hypothesis.

Comment: Good first guess. I expect you're right, but given the obvious American alternative, it might be worth a **buck** or two to see some proof.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger That would require the OP to provide actual context.